# Function inlining—what are examples where it hurt performance?

Tags: c++, c, inline

It's conventional wisdom that function inlining doesn't always benefit, and can even hurt performance:

- [The Linux kernel style guide](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/Documentation/CodingStyle#L692) warns against excessive inlining
- Google also [recommends programmers be careful with inlining](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Inline_Functions)
- The [C++ FAQ lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.3) says more of the same

I understand why inlining is supposed to help—it eliminates function call overhead by including the called function in its caller.

I also understand why people claim it can hurt performance—inlining functions can in some cases increase code size, which can eventually increase cache misses or even trigger extra page faults. This all makes sense.

I'm having trouble, though, finding specific examples where inlining actually hurts performance. Surely if it's enough of a problem to be worth warning about it, someone somewhere must have come across an example where inlining is a problem. So, I ask…

What is a good, concrete example of code where performance is actually hurt by function inlining?

Comment: Usually the compiler will avoid it for you, so it's hard to find examples of it happening since the compiler has already guarded against it.

Comment: Fair enough, but even so I'd expect it to happen occasionally, especially given all the warnings around the 'Net to be careful with the feature.

Comment: "Excessive" anything is not good, by definition! :-) However, some of these warnings are perhaps a bit old? Compilers are getting better, both at selecting what to inline and at optimizing the inlined code. And cache sizes are growing. The Linux Kernel guys are hardcore C persons, who have never seen that inlining small member functions in C++ results in code that is both smaller and faster at the same time.

Comment: Inlining member functions also makes the calling code depend on the implementation of the class - something very very bad if you're writing library code or using shared libraries... The proper solution is to fix the compiler so it doesn't emit function entry prologue and epilogue for small "hot paths" in functions where it can avoid it. Then the call is no more expensive than the inline code, but it still avoids making the implementation of an object part of the ABI for the library.

Comment: "Guess what?! I got a fever, and the only prescription is more `inline!`" - THE Bruce Dickinson

Comment: @Michael Thank you! That's the best thing I've read all day!

Comment: most often, any performance effects are just invisible. When optimizing, only 5-10% of the code actually *matters*. And the same is true when investigating the effects of inlining. 95% of the code can be inlined, or left not inlined, and it won't make a noticeable difference either way. So no, unless you specifically profile and test and tweak and tune your code, the effects of inlining aren't really visible. And if you do that, then you obviously won't force the compiler to inline if the effects are negative. So no, you typically don't see a performance decrease due to inlining "in the wild"

Answer (score 6):

On some platforms, with large inlined functions, performance can be reduced by causing a "far" jump rather than a relative jump.  Inlining may also cause a page fault where the OS needs to haul in more code into memory, rather than executing code with may already exist (as a subroutine).

Some platforms may have optimized jump instructions for "near code".  This type of jump uses a signed offset from the current position.  The signed offsets may be restricted, for example 127 bytes.  A long jump would require a bigger instruction because the longer jump must include the absolute address.  Longer instructions take more time to execute.

Long inlined functions may expand the length of the executable so that the OS needs to haul in a new "page" into memory, called a page swap.  Page swapping slows down execution speed of an application.

These are "possible" reasons how inlined code could slow performance.  The real truth is obtained by profiling.

Comment: +1 for a possible cause I hadn't thought of and suggesting profiling :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the case in our project in C (gcc). My collegue abused inlines in his library, forcing `-fno-inline` reduced the CPU time by 10% (on SUN V890 with Ultrasparc IV+ processors).

Comment: I'd be interested in any details you might have on the specifics of the abuse (for example, any data on the difference in the size of the executable images with and without `-fno-inline`?).

Comment: To give an idea, the library that was affected by that problem compiles with gcc 3.4.6 to a size of 806160 bytes, when supplying a -fno-inline it compiles to a size of only 635632. On the tested version it was even worse, it was compiled with gcc 3.3.1 and the difference was 849104 to 693320.

Comment: To give an idea of the disaster, there are about 20 inline functions, the smallest one is 1 line and deserves its inline status, but most of his functions are betwen 50 and 150 lines long. The longest is called 5 times (OMG by checking I just discovered that this 150 line behemoth "calls" 2*4 other inlines of 50 lines each). It's equivalent of 5*(150+8*50)=2750 lines of C code instead of 4*50+150=350 lines. And that's only for one part of the lib, there are 3 others with similar code. If it wasn't so big I would have sent it to DailyWTF already.

Comment: @tristopia: Sometimes expanding out even large functions can be useful if the expanded-out versions can fill in compile-time constants. That can go double on some embedded systems (e.g. if `moo` is an `int` field at offset 4 of a structure, on one processor I've used, the statement `myStruct.moo = 4;` could compile to code about a third the size of `myStructPtr->moo = 4;`. If one has a two structures, and a lot of code that uses them the same way, the result of expanding out the code twice may be smaller than passing a pointer to a method. Of course, I knew the target compiler when doing that.

Answer (score 3):

Something not mentioned yet is that inlining of big functions into other big functions can cause excessive register spilling, hurting not only the the quality of the compiled code but also adding more overhead than was eliminated by the inline (and it max even screw up global and local optimization heurstics, iirc msdn has a warning about this under `__forceinline`). Other 'constructs' such as inline non-naked asm put in inlines may produce unneeded stack frames, or inlines with special alignment requirements, or even those that just push the stack allocation into the range where the compiler shoves in stack checking allocation(`_chkstk` under msvc).

Comment: I had a case like this where a fairly big function with a loop called several other functions. By testing I found that using `__forceinline` sometimes helped, sometimes hurt. VC++ appeared to have a hard time determining which was correct which is understandable because the path of execution depended heavily on the data passed to this function. In this case, I tested with what I thought was the most likely types of data the function would see.

Comment: I had a situation exactly like this - a reasonably large function, which performed a few simple loops with typically 1,000 iterations per loop, but doing that very often, so it was quite performance critical for the whole application. The compiled code for the loops was bad. Extracting them into separate functions didn't help because of inlining. Extracting them into separate functions in a separate file made the code a lot faster - the same loop kept everything in registers instead of using four or five variables on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think inlining hurts performance other than indirectly relating to the code being larger, which I think you described.

In general, inlining improves performance by eliminating the call and return.

Answer (score 2):

[In reference to inline functions]

> The function is placed in the code,
>   rather than being called, similar to
>   using macros (conceptually)
>
> **This can improve speed (no function
>   call), but causes code bloat (if the
>   function is used 100 times, you now
>   have 100 copies)**
>
> You should note this does not force
>   the compiler to make the function
>   inline, and it will ignore you if it
>   thinks its a bad idea. Similarly the
>   compiler may decided to make normal
>   functions inline for you.
>
> This also allows you to place the
>   entire function in a header file,
>   rather than implementing it in a cpp
>   file (which you cant anyways, since
>   then you get an unresolved external if
>   it was declared inline, unless of
>   course only that cpp file used it).

[Quote snagged from SO user 'Fire Lancer' so credit him]

Comment: @KyleM: I think a link to the source of the quote would be nice.

Comment: I understand all of this, but I've done some searching and I'm not able to find any real examples where inlining has caused enough bloat to be a problem. I can't even find intentionally constructed examples where this happens.

Comment: Actually, inlining can also make the code smaller, depending on how much code setting up the stack and calling a function takes, compared to what's in the body of the function.

Comment: @LnxPrgr: In general, inlining doesn't cause problems. That's why it's used. Obviously, some people prefer their applications to be smaller rather than larger and use less memory rather than more. Other than that, I sort of see you having trouble looking for an example of a problem that doesn't really exist.

Comment: @Jonathan I _have_ been able to generate an example where compiling all but one file with -Os (the one file being compiled with -O3) generated measurably faster code than when the whole program was compiled at -O3. This was no contrived example either—it was the LAME mp3 encoder.

Comment: @LnxPrgr3: I'm not sure what -O3 does but how does this address my point? -Os generates smaller code but the compiler has great leeway in exactly how it does that. While it often doesn't generate faster code, I'm not the least bit surprised when it does. This is hardly a measure of the difference between inlining and not inlining. I still don't understand why you're concerned about this.

Comment: @Jonathan No, it doesn't measure the effect of inlining specifically, but it _does_ hint at the effect code size can have on performance. The compiler's not magic either, and -Os certainly doesn't, on average, generate faster code than -O3. Compiling all of LAME with -Os, for example, resulted in a measurably slower binary. Compile just the file where profiling revealed it spending most of its time with -O3, and suddenly it's better than when the whole program's built that way. Surely everything else being faster too wouldn't _hurt_, would it? What conclusion would you draw from this?

Comment: @LnxPrgr3: As indicated previously, I don't even know what -O3 does off the top of my head. But modern compilers are so sophisticated these days that it's hard to draw too much from it. The difference could be minor or it could involve hundreds of different types of changes. Either way, I certainly wouldn't assume it's faster because of less inlining.

Answer (score 2):

I have no hard data to back this up, but in the case of the Linux kernel anyway (since the "The Linux kernel style guide" was cited in the question), code size could impact performance because the kernel code occupies physical memory regardless of instruction caching (kernel pages are never paged out).

Memory pages that are used by the kernel are permanently unavailable for user virtual memory.  So if you're using memory pages for inlined code copied that have dubious benefit (the call overhead is generally small for functions that are large), you're having a negative impact on the system for no real benefit.

Answer (score 1):

why do you need concrete examples of where inlining hurt performance? It is such a context sensitive issue. It depends on a number of hardware factors, including speed of RAM, CPU model, compiler version and a number of other factors. It's possible to create such an example on my computer, but which will still be faster than the non-inlined version no yours. And inlining, in turn, may enable dozens of *other* compiler optimizations that would not otherwise be performed. So even in a case where the code bloat causes a performance hit, it may enable some compilers to perform a number of other optimizations to compensate for it.

So you're not going to get a more meaningful answer than the theory, of *why* it may produce slower code.

If you need a specific example of where performance can be hurt by inlining, then go ahead and write it. It's not that difficult once you know the theory.

You want a function that is big enough to pollute the cache if inlined, and you want to call it from several different, but closely related, places (if you call it from two completely separate modules, then the two instantiations of the function won't compete for the cache space anyway. But if you alternate quickly between several different call sites, then each instantiation may force the previous one out of cache.

And of course, the function must be written so that little of it can get eliminated when it is inlined. If, upon inlining, the compiler is able to eliminate 80% of the code, then that'll mitigate the performance hit you might otherwise take.

And finally, you'll likely need to force it to be inlined. At best, compilers tend to treat the `inline` keyword as a hint (sometimes not even that). So you'll likely have to look up compiler-specific ways to force a function to be inlined.

You may also want to disable other optimizations, as the compiler might otherwise be able to optimize the inlined version.

So it's pretty straightforward to produce slower code through inlining, once you know what to do. But it's quite a lot of work to do so, especially if you want anything near predictable or deterministic results. And despite your efforts, next year's compilers or next year's CPUs may again be able to outsmart you and produce faster code from your intentionally "over-inlined" code.

So I just don't see why you'd need to do this. Accept that excessive inlining can hurt in some cases, and understand *why* it can hurt. Beyond that, why bother?

A final point is that those warnings are often misguided, because there's very little to warn about. *Because* the compiler typically chooses by itself what to inline, and, at best, treats the `inline` keyword as a hint, it generally *doesn't matter* whether or not you try to inline everything.

So while it is true that excessive inlining can hurt performance, excessive use of the `inline` keyword *usually* doesn't.

The `inline` keyword has other effects, which should guide its usage. Use it when you want to disable the One Definition Rule, to prevent linker errors when a function is defined in multiple translation units.

Comment: I think the question is a good one. I could be wrong, but I think the OP may be wondering if "too much inline is bad" is now a cargo-cult mantra. In fact, saying that compilers are smart enough to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot with too much inline is an argument that you should go ahead and inline everything (and let the compiler sort it out).

Comment: Why are you (and others) questioning my motivation? I'm simply looking for real-world evidence of a theoretical phenomenon. Is there something deeply wrong with that?

Comment: @Lnx: I'm not "questioning" anything, I am explaining why it is misguided, and why, even if you found such a real-world example, it would be worthless. Like I said, you could find a snippet of code which, on 3 year old hardware, with a 3 year old compiler, became slower when inlined, but which runs perfectly well today.

Comment: @Michael: you can't inline everything. Not without putting everything in headers, which has a few other inconvenient side effects (like hurting compile times). And given that compilers are smart enough to deal with this, it is certainly not an argument in favor of inlining *everything*. It is an argument in favor of leaving the inlining to the compiler. Mark functions as `inline` when you need the *semantic* difference it makes. And if it's just for optimization purposes, leave it alone until profiling has shown that it's a problem.

Comment: But note that I didn't say it was a bad question. My point is that there are no good *answers* possible. Because even if we give the OP what he's asking for, an example of code that becomes slower with inlining, it doesn't tell us anything useful, because it depends on a dozen different factors, and it might no longer be slower tomorrow.

Comment: by the way, I've seen performance decrease when inlining was enabled on a project I did on the Cell processor. We gained some 10-15% performance by disabling inlining. But as I said in my answer, I don't feel this is important, because it's such a transient result. If I did the same test today, I might get completely different results. Hence why I'm not editing it into the question.

Comment: @jalf I realize any one example won't apply for the rest of time on all platforms, but examples go a long way toward showing that the theoretical problem can appear in the real world. If that's the case, to me that's just one more reason to profile instead of making assumptions about performance, which is something I wish people would do more often.

Comment: @jalf Thanks for the most reasonable advice I've ever read on when to use the inline keyword, btw! Besides, I believe clang can inline across compilation units (with -O4) no matter what you asked for anyway.

Comment: @LnxPrg3: other compilers can do the same (in VC++, it's called link-time code generation, and GCC has a similar option), so yeah, in the end, the compiler will inline pretty much anything it likes. :) By the way, I absolutely agree, the only *really* meaningful rule regarding inlining is "profile, and see what's faster in *your* case". That's much more valuable than all the  "don't inline excessively" advice in the world. :)

Comment: From experience with time critical code, there are situations where gcc produces stupidly bad code, and clang produces the exact same stupidly bad code. So when someone says "it's bad on a three your old computer with a three your old compiler", I'm much more pessimistic than that.